# How do I prove the following equality? $(C \cup (A^C \cup(B−A))^C)^C=(A−A)^C \cap((C^C \cap A)−(C^C \cap B))\cup C^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the sets A, B, C ⊆ U be such that A ⊆ C. Prove the following equality by means of the laws of set algebra:

$$\biggl(C \cup \Bigl(A^C \cup (B-A)\Bigr)^C\biggr)^C = (A-A)^C \cap \Bigl((C^C \cap A)-(C^C \cap B)\Bigr) \cup C^C$$

This is what I have done:

$$\biggl(C \cup \Bigl(A^C \cup (B-A)\Bigr)^C\biggr)^C = (A-A)^C \cap \Bigl((C^C \cap A)-(C^C \cap B)\Bigr) \cup C^C$$

$$ \varnothing^C \cap \bigl((C^C \cap A) - (C^C \cap B)\bigr) \cup C^C    \text{ by Set Difference Law} $$

$$ U \cap \bigl((C^C \cap A) - (C^C \cap B)\bigr) \cup C^C       \text{ by Complement Law} $$

$$ \bigl((C^C \cap A) - (C^C \cap B)\bigr) \cup C^C              \text{ by Identity Law} $$

$$ \bigl((C^C \cap A) \cap (C^C \cap B)^C \bigr) \cup C^C        \text{ by Set Difference Law} $$

$$ \bigl((C^C \cap A) \cap C \cup B^C \bigr) \cup C^C            \text{ by De Morgan Law} $$

So, as you can see, I am pretty confused about how to go about solving this. Does anyone have any ideas? By the way, I would appreciate if you could state which theorems you applied to reach your answer.

P.S. In case that you think that something that I wrote sounds somewhat weird, I translated this from Spanish.

Comment: In general $X \cap (Y \cup Z) \neq (X \cap Y) \cup Z$ so it looks like the right side of what you want to prove is ambiguous.

Comment: @coffeemath Could you please elaborate? Not only because I would like to know the detailed explanation of why this does not have a solution, but also because I need to hand in this task before 24:00 of today.

Comment: The left side is a subset of $X$ so if $Z$ has an element not in $X$ then that element is in the right side but not in the left side.

Comment: I did not use $A \subseteq C$ in my comment, so that comment may be irrelevant.

Comment: Why not format the subject line too? It's incomprehensible right now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're simplifying the right-hand side, so you just need to continue:

$$((C^C \cap A) \cap (C \cup B^C)) \cup C^C$$
= (distribution) $$((C^C \cap A \cap C) \cup (C^C \cap A \cap B^C)) \cup C^C$$
= (complement is disjoint) $$(\emptyset \cup (C^C \cap A \cap B^C)) \cup C^C$$
= (union with empty set does nothing) $$(C^C \cap A \cap B^C) \cup C^C$$
= (union with subset does nothing) $$C^C.$$
However, the left-hand side appears to simplify to $C^C \cap A^C$, so it looks like your original statement is false. Perhaps the right-hand side should instead be $A^C \cap ...$.